# jQuery $.inArray still passing value even if it checked for existence

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using $.inArray to check if value is in array. if it is not I want to add it, else do nothing.

```
var arrayValues = [1];

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

    if($.inArray('1', arrayValues) === -1) {

        arrayValues.push(0+i);  

    }

}
```

I am getting data on ajax page load as `valuesArray = [value, value2];` on second load I get valuesArray `valuesArray = [value, value2, value3, value4];` on third load I get `value` again and it still pushing it to `valuesArray` as `valuesArray = [value, value2, value3, value4, value];`.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Please see live example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfugH/).

Comment: Is it `'value'` or `value` ? Do you know that object1==object2 only if it's the same reference ? Please give us a working relevant code if you want an answer.

Comment: `if('value', valuesArray)) === -1)` What is supposed to do? Forgot to use $.inArray()?!

Comment: Sorry, was writing quickly on a break. Fixed.

Comment: There's still no visible relation between your code and the behavior you describe.

Comment: @ignaty could you answer first dystroy's question: it is value or 'value'?

Comment: Updated with live example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the number `1` in the array but check for the presence of the string `"1"`. They're not equal for `$.inArray`.

You could do this :

```
if($.inArray(1, arrayValues) === -1) { // <- test with a number, not a string
    arrayValues.push(0+i); // note that the 0+ here is useless
}
```

While `1=='1'`, `1!=='1'` and `$.inArray` tests using `===` as can be seen in the source code :

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    var len;

    if ( arr ) {
        if ( core_indexOf ) {
            return core_indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
        }

        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
},
```

More information on `==` vs `===` [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample never calls `$.inArray`.  It has syntax errors because there are multiple unclosed parens.

```
if($.inArray('value', valuesArray) === -1) {

    valuesArray.push(value);  

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: Sorry, was writing quickly on a break. Fixed.

Comment: @dystroy It was an answer, but the question shifted on me.

Comment: You only noticed, like commentators, that there were obvious typos in the question. An answer is supposed to help solve the real problem, not point an error that isn't, obviously, in the real used code.

Comment: @Sorry, next time I will do a better job of predicting that the OP was rushing an answer during their break and discerning that the provide code was just not bug ridden.

Comment: Sorry for that Kevin. Answer is updated with live example.

Comment: @KevinBowersox if you were a new user, this wouldn't be an issue. But you're a trusted user with over 20k rep. You're not supposed to do this kind of stupid stuff.